# IF condition not working in UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysqli

In this code when I want to update the status from Pending to Accepted that time If statement not working.
In database I keep Pending by default. Problem is that when I'm going to update the status the STATUS will update but the code inside the If condition can't work.
please help me out from this problem.
Thanks in advance.

```html
 <?php
include("connect.php");//conection
if(isset($_REQUEST['leave_id']))
{
$id=$_REQUEST['leave_id'];
}
else
{
$id=NULL;
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TAKEN_LEAVES,BALANCE_LEAVE,STATUS 
                              FROM xxxemi_person_leave_t
                              WHERE leave_id= $id");
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
 
 $taken_leave = $res['TAKEN_LEAVES'];
 $balance_leave = $res['BALANCE_LEAVE'];
 $status = $res['STATUS'];

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
          {
    if ($status=='ACCEPTED')
    {
   $status = $_POST['USTATUS'];
   $updated_balance_leave = $_POST['UBALANCE_LEAVE'];

   $updated_balance_leave = $balance_leave - $taken_leave;   
          
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE xxxemi_person_leave_t 
                      SET STATUS ='$status', BALANCE_LEAVE ='$updated_balance_leave'
        WHERE leave_id = '$id' "); 

        echo "<script>alert('Your Record Updated');</script>";
       
     }

      else 
    {
     $status = $_POST['USTATUS'];
    
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE xxxemi_person_leave_t 
                      SET STATUS ='$status' 
        WHERE leave_id = '$id' "); 

        echo "<script>alert('Your Record Updated');</script>";
       
     }
  }
     
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
/**************PHP CODE *******/
   <form method="post">
             <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['leave_id'];?>>
 
             <input type="hidden" name="UBALANCE_LEAVE" value="<?php echo $updated_balance_leave;?>">

              <input type="checkbox"  name="USTATUS" value="ACCEPTED" />
              <img src="images/Approved.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <input type="checkbox" name="USTATUS" value="REJECTED" />
              <img src="images/Rejected.png" /></td>

              <input type="submit" name="save" value="Update">
            </form>
/************* HTML CODE**********/
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: _"If statement not working."_ - Not working how? And which if-statement, you have two?

Comment: You have a typo: `$statu = $res['STATUS']` and `if ($status=='ACCEPTED')` (you're missing the last `s` on `$status` when you define the variable).

Comment: `leave_id = '$id'` - The variable `$id` isn't defined in your example. Is it defined before this snippet?

Comment: You're setting the variable `$rl` from the post array, just to completely overwrite it in the next line.

Comment: Your `header('location: ....)` would probably throw a _"Headers already sent"_ warning. [Here's why...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ,you are using `$statu = $res['STATUS']; // STATUS`
`$statu` for `STATUS`, but in if condition you are checking for `$status`

---

Change This

```
if ($status=='ACCEPTED')
```

To

```
 if($_POST['USTATUS']=='ACCEPTED')
```

AND  `type="checkbox"` TO  `type="radio"`

Comment: Sir I have posted another code. Please check it and suggest me solution. Thanx & Regards

Comment: Print your `$status` before checking, for value stored in `$status` @ArpitMaheshwari

Comment: It shows PENDING before updation . Because it is by default pending in database.
when I update the Status it will change but the Updated_balance_leave not update.

Comment: because of `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TAKEN_LEAVES,BALANCE_LEAVE,STATUS 
                              FROM xxxemi_person_leave_t
                              WHERE leave_id= $id");
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
 
 $taken_leave = $res['TAKEN_LEAVES'];
 $balance_leave = $res['BALANCE_LEAVE'];
 $status = $res['STATUS'];` code, check this code output first

Comment: OUTPUT: PENDING

Comment: Now read this code `if ($status=='ACCEPTED')
    {` , if your `$status` value is `PENDING' then how this condition will work ?

Comment: Please help me sir.
My condition is I want When I change the Status Pending to Accepted that time the balance leave will also update and When I change the Status Pending to Rejected the Balance leave remain the same.